# How long the activity was open?

Tags: java, android, xml, time, android-activity

I'm new in android programming and I'm making a very simple app.
I only have one text view and one button, and when I click the button I want to show in the text view a value that represents how long the activity was open.

this is my xml file:

```
    <Button
        android:id = "@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text=" " />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my java file:

```
package com.diogoc.teste;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textView;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(Listener);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private OnClickListener Listener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //It's here
            textView.setText("You take");
        }
    };

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Take the current time in `onCreate` and show the difference to it in your `TextView`, possibly updating it every once in a while.

Comment: What "open" is depends. I'd say either since the last `onStart` (visible) or even the last `onResume` (focus in foreground). See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Can anyone exemplify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this member variable to the class:

```
long startTime;
```

Add this to your onCreate()-method:

```
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Add this to your onClick()-method:

```
long timeElapsedMS = System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime; //gets the time difference in milliseconds
long timeElapsedSeconds = timeElapsedMS/1000;
textView.setText("You took "+timeElapsedSeconds+" seconds");
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in your `onCreate` will work:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /* Other stuff omitted */
    final long start= System.currentTimeMillis();
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            textView.setText(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    }, 100);
}
```

The code in the `run()` method will run indefinately every 100 ms, updating the text in your textview with the milliseconds passed since the call to `onCreate()`.

Comment: I think I did not explain myself well. 
I want the textview say how long it took until he click the button.

Comment: This example should show you the tools you need to achieve that. We aren't going to just do all your work for you.

Comment: So if I want to represent in seconds I must divide the value by 1000 or exist another way?

Comment: You can divide by 1000 to get from milliseconds to seconds indeed.